# Get Distribution Group Members list and nested members via powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to get Distribution Group Members list and nested groups. When attempting to run my script then I got the following the error message.

Message:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSObject] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'.
At line:54 char:1
+ $output += $UserObj
```

Script :

```
$CSVfile = "C:\tmp\DG.csv"

$AllDG = Get-DistributionGroup -resultsize unlimited

Foreach($dg in $allDg)

{

$Members = Get-DistributionGroupMember $Dg.name -resultsize unlimited

if($members.count -eq 0)
{
$managers = $Dg | Select @{Name='DistributionGroupManagers';Expression={[string]::join(";", ($_.Managedby))}}

$userObj = New-Object PSObject

$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "DisplayName" -Value EmptyGroup
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Alias" -Value EmptyGroup
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "RecipientType" -Value EmptyGroup
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Recipient OU" -Value EmptyGroup
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Primary SMTP address" -Value EmptyGroup
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Distribution Group" -Value $DG.Name
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Distribution Group Primary SMTP address" -Value $DG.PrimarySmtpAddress
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Distribution Group Managers" -Value $managers.DistributionGroupManagers
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Distribution Group OU" -Value $DG.OrganizationalUnit
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Distribution Group Type" -Value $DG.GroupType
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Distribution Group Recipient Type" -Value $DG.RecipientType

$output += $UserObj  

}
else
{
Foreach($Member in $members)
 {

$managers = $Dg | Select @{Name='DistributionGroupManagers';Expression={[string]::join(";", ($_.Managedby))}}

$userObj = New-Object PSObject

$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "DisplayName" -Value $Member.Name
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Alias" -Value $Member.Alias
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "RecipientType" -Value $Member.RecipientType
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Recipient OU" -Value $Member.OrganizationalUnit
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Primary SMTP address" -Value $Member.PrimarySmtpAddress
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Distribution Group" -Value $DG.Name
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Distribution Group Primary SMTP address" -Value $DG.PrimarySmtpAddress
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Distribution Group Managers" -Value $managers.DistributionGroupManagers
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Distribution Group OU" -Value $DG.OrganizationalUnit
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Distribution Group Type" -Value $DG.GroupType
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Distribution Group Recipient Type" -Value $DG.RecipientType

$output += $UserObj  

 }
}

$output | Export-csv -Path $CSVfile -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8

}
```

Comment: You forgot to define `$output` as array on top. Far better is to not use `+=`, but to do `$output = Foreach($dg in $allDg){...` and simply emit the objects in the loop

Answer (score 0):

I’m thinking adding the following near the top of your script should make it work:

```
$output = @()
```